# How do I cast an int value to a generic type parameter that is equivalent such as char?

Tags: c#, generics, casting, linked-list, type-conversion

I'm new to generics and I'm having some trouble implementing a small self practice code.

I'm creating a linked list. I want it to store char or int values. So I decided to make the implementation generic:

```
public class Node<T> where T : struct, IConvertible
{
    public Node<T> next = null;
    public T data = default(T);

    public Node(T value) { this.data = value; }
}
```

I have a method that creates the linked list by generating random values in the range [33,127), converting the value to the type specified by T (e.g. if 86 is generated and T is Char, then the value to be stored in the linked list node will be 'V'; If T is Int32, then value will simply be 86). I'm facing two problems:

```
    static Node<IConvertible> CreateList<T>(int len) where T : struct, IConvertible
    {
        Random r = new Random((int)DateTime.Now.Ticks);
        T value = (T)r.Next(33, 127);       // Problem #1

        Node<T> head = new Node<T>(value);
        Node<T> n = head;

        for (int i = 1; i < len; i++)
        {
            n.next = new Node<T>(value);
            n = n.next;
        }
        return head;  // Problem #2
    }
```

These are the problems :

1) Normally this is possible: (int) value = (char) r.Next(33, 127). Why if T is of type Char, the compiler says "Cannot convert type 'int' to 'T'", even if I had specified "where T : struct, IConvertible"?

2) "Cannot implicitly convert type '`LinkedList.Node<T>`' to '`LinkedList.Node<System.IConvertible>`'" If T is either Int32 or Char and both of them implement IConvertible, what is the way to cast `Node<Int32>` or `Node<Char>` to `Node<IConvertible>` ?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 6):

The issue is that **T** could be any struct, e.g. Guid, SByte... or *custom-new-one*. and while we can be sure that **T** is `struct` and `IConvertible`, there does not have to be explicit cast operator to

```
public static explicit operator AnyStruct(int i)
```

The second issue casting `Node<System.IConvertible>` to `Node<System.IConvertible>` is usual. Any list `List<T>` cannot be converted to `List<System.IConvertible>`.

What we need is covariance declaration on interface: `INode<out T>`. Then the `INode<T>` could be converted into `INode<System.IConvertible>`

Answer (score 2):

Use

```
T value = (T)Convert.ChangeType(r.Next(33, 127), typeof(T));
```

Answer (score 2):

Your use of `Random` to generate some data is sort of at odds with using generics. I would separate the two like so:

```
static Node<T> CreateList<T>(int len, Func<T> dataProvider) where T : struct, IConvertible
{   
    Node<T> head = new Node<T>(dataProvider());
    Node<T> n = head;

    for (int i = 1; i < len; i++)
    {
        n.next = new Node<T>(dataProvider());
        n = n.next;
    }
    return head;
}
```

calling code:

```
Random r = new Random();
Node<char> list = CreateList(10, () => (char)r.Next(33, 127));
```

The second issue is `Node<IConvertible>` isn't allowed by your `struct` constraint on `Node<T>`. Just return a `Node<T>`. Even if you do remove the `struct` constraint from `Node<T>`, it would not be possible to return a `Node<IConvertible>` because generic classes do not support variance.